# Requesting MathJax/Latex Support

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but can we get MathJax/Latex support in here for more serious questions?

**NOTE:** We have MathJax. Put away pitchforks.

**Also:** Thank you SE powers.

Comment: It is not for "more serious questions" - it if for _all_ questions, in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Alecos--what do you mean by "more serious questions"?

Comment: Economics is a math heavy subject. Even though the math stackexchange has the economics tag it is not the place for discussing economics graduate concepts and ideas that use graduate level calculus because its not only the math that matters, but also the theory. WE NEED LATEX SUPPORT!

Comment: @SteveS I meant that we're all handicapped by the lack of support, and it deters contributions that would require the ability to express complex equations. Some simple questions can be asked without it (and even many complex ones), but I think it's important to have.

Answer (score 6):

Irrespective of the arguments, and the votes on the matter, in Area 51, SE activated the private Beta without MathJax. No comment.

Once again: "Economics" lives as a tag in math.SE already:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics

We don't need to show *again* that MathJax is vital for *this* site, but let's provide one example:

This is an ugly looking question
[First Order Condition for Profit Maximization in Gambling Industry](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/11/first-order-condition-for-profit-maximization-in-gambling-industry)

and I cannot post the answer I wanted to.

And I cannot participate here, without MathJax. So, until things change, good luck.

Comment: Physics tag also lives within math.SE, yet there is a physics stackexchange.

Comment: @Koba I don't understand your comment. The fact that "Economics" is a tag in math.SE should have provide sufficient input for the SE team to know beforehand that in the Economics site proper, MathJax should have been activated from the very beginning. Do you disagree with that?

Comment: Oh I misread your question. I absolutely agree with you and for latex support. Sending the SE an email right now. I think we all should do it.

Comment: @Koba care to share the e-mail?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos MathJax is off by default on all our sites and we don't attempt to guess which communities will want or need it. However, there are no objections to enabling it here on our end. Sorry about the inconvenience.

Comment: And, uh, @Koba there's really no need to encourage folks to send us multiple emails when a meta post does the job nicely.

Comment: @AnnaLear Thank you Anna, and the SE team, for this light-speed response!

Comment: @AnnaLear Thank you thank you. :-)

Comment: Nice to see that my question was a shining example of how ugly things are without MathJax :)

@AlecosPapadopoulos Much thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: @AnnaLear oh my fault. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 4):

I'm starting a community wiki for questions that we think could really use MathJax.

- [First Order Condition for Profit Maximization in Gambling Industry](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/11/first-order-condition-for-profit-maximization-in-gambling-industry)
- [The relation between the Black-Scholes model and quantum mechanics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6/the-relation-between-the-black-scholes-model-and-quantum-mechanics)
- [Is elasticity meaningful in my, or any, regression?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/17/econometrics-is-elasticity-meaningful-in-my-or-any-regression)

Answer (score 1):

**MathJax test**

When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to (ax^2 + bx + c = 0) and they are
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$

Comment: And it works on mobile!